# Как определить, что точка выше вектора

Tags: unity3d

Для двумерного проекта.
Есть объект vector2, есть ли простой способ определить, что точка (x,y) находится выше него? Или только путем заморочек с уравнением прямой и т.д?

Comment: а почему с уравнением прямой заморочки? по-моему это самый простой путь, как раз-таки

Comment: Y координату - нет. Вектор под наклоном может идти. Ладно, буду делать через уравнение прямой

Comment: @ValeraKvip не все так просто. Y координату какой точки? начала вектора или конец? вектор может идти сверху, а может снизу, а точка может находится вообще выше обеих, а может и не находится)) С иксом та же ситуация.... Придется писать много условий. Получится знатный костыль))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из способов:

```
Vector2 line;
Vector2 point;
```

---

```
 line /= line.x;//приводим координату x к 1, направление сохраняется
 if (point.y > line.y * point.x){
     //точка над линией
 }
```

Можно короче и без изменения line, алгоритм тот же:

```
if (point.y > line.y / line.x * point.x){
     //точка над линией
}
```

Comment: главное не забыть о вертикальных линиях (line.x==0)

Comment: Да верно, но для данной задачи данного решения достаточно

Comment: Я так понимаю тут косое произведение происходит? но разве для определения точки относительно вектора не нужно знать именно две координаты вектора и координаты точки?

Comment: Чтобы получить прямую нужно две точки, одна точка - сам объект Vector2, вторая не указывается, следовательно можно предположить что это (0,0)

Comment: Кстати, было бы неплохо, если бы было объяснено, что за магия тут творится. Для остальных людей. Понятно, что можно изучать вычислительную геометрию и при gamedev оно нужно, но.... изложить суть бы... ;-)

Comment: Просто выводится функция линии, вида **y = f(x)**, задаем координату **x** получаем координату **y** точки на линии. Сверяем **y** координаты.

Comment: `f(x) = tg(a)x, tg(a) = yline/xline, ypoint = f(xpoint) = yline/xline * xpoint, где ypoint - точка на линии с координатой xpoint`